# Vibration listener in Android

Tags: android, listener, vibration

Is it possible to listen for phone vibration in Android?
Basically, I need my background component to wake-up and do some stuff whenever the phone vibrates.

Comment: Are you trying to wake up whenever the phone vibrates for any reason? Or are you trying to wake up when there's a call?

Comment: Yeah.  I am trying to wake up whenever the phone vibrates for any reason.

Comment: [An okey answer is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862965/detect-the-device-is-vibrating/36455200#36455200) Similar question was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to listen for phone vibration in Android?

Sorry, no, not without custom firmware.