# Check if the android device is vibrating now

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, android-vibration

Is it possible to detect vibration in android device via code.
I'm building an app using accelerometer, so want to give different condtions when the device is vibrating.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean vibrating by the device (ex. a push notification came in) or by external force (ex. by shaking the device)?

Comment: vibration due to a notification, like a message or call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the documenation and as far as I can see this is not possible. There is no listener for vibration... See this question: [Vibration listener in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343366/vibration-listener-in-android)

Also, the vibration of the phone may be too weak to detect it via [Shake Listener](http://jasonmcreynolds.com/?p=388)