# Detect the device is vibrating?

Tags: android, events, android-vibration, vibration

I have used the below code to vibrate the device.

```
public void vibrator() {
    try {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "vibrator exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

Can we programmatically detect this event (check is device vibrating)?

Comment: I guess, there is no callbacks for checking if the Vibrator is vibrating for now.

Comment: When you say you want to check if the device is vibrating - **do you wish to check if your own app is making it vibrate, or any other application/services?**

Comment: i want to check is my Application making it vibrate.

Comment: Please see my answer for a possible solution that allows you to track when your application `isVibrating()`.

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

The [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class does not have the `isVibrating()` method that you are looking for. It uses services, so you cannot easily override [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) and add in the extra functionality.

## ManagedVibrator

Below, is a ManagedVibrator class that is a wrapper for the [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class. All [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) methods are included, with the additional `isVibrating()` method.

The [constant vibration methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long[],%20int%29) with signatures that accept `long[] pattern` are easy to track because [`cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#cancel%28%29) needs to be called to end the vibration. However, the [one time vibration methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%29) with signatures that accept `long millseconds` are much harder to track.

This implementation uses a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor%28int%29) to track [one time validation methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%29). It sets the `mIsVibrating` flag to `false` just after a [one time vibration method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%29) finishes.

```
public class ManagedVibrator {

    public static final String TAG = ManagedVibrator.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private Vibrator mVibrator;
    private boolean mIsVibrating = false;
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mExecutor;

    private Runnable mVibrationEndRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVibrating(false);
        }
    };

    public ManagedVibrator(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mVibrator = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        mExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    }

    public boolean hasVibrator() {
        return mVibrator.hasVibrator();
    }

    public void vibrate(long milliseconds) {
        setVibrating(true);
        mVibrator.vibrate(milliseconds);
        notifyOnVibrationEnd(milliseconds);
    }

    // Requires API v21
    public void vibrate(long milliseconds, AudioAttributes attributes) {
        setVibrating(true);
        mVibrator.vibrate(milliseconds, attributes);
        notifyOnVibrationEnd(milliseconds);
    }

    public void vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat) {
        setVibrating(true);
        mVibrator.vibrate(pattern, repeat);
    }

    // Requires API v21
    public void vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat, AudioAttributes attributes) {
        setVibrating(true);
        mVibrator.vibrate(pattern, repeat, attributes);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        mVibrator.cancel();
        setVibrating(false);
    }

    public boolean isVibrating() {
        return mIsVibrating;
    }

    private void setVibrating(boolean isVibrating) {
        mIsVibrating = isVibrating;
    }

    private void notifyOnVibrationEnd(long milliseconds) {
        try {
            mExecutor.schedule(mVibrationEndRunnable, milliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

## Usage

```
ManagedVibrator vibrator = new ManagedVibrator(this);
vibrator.vibrate(5000);
...
if (vibrator.isVibrating()) {
    // Do something
}
```

## Limitations

1. You need to **use one ManagedVibrator instance** in your application
2. ManagedVibrator can only tell you about vibrations initiated by your application. **It does not know anything about vibrations caused by other applications of services.**
3. Very long vibration times or very frequent one time vibrations may cause issues

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

Same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343366/vibration-listener-in-android).

You can check only if the device vibrating is supported:

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
boolean hasVibrator = mVibrator.hasVibrator();
```

**See more:**

- [Android Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bad way for rooted phones but you will get atleast something.

You can read the file at:

```
"/sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable"
```

It stores the time left as microseconds when the device is vibrating.
(tried on 5.1)

For unrooted phones, you can just check `"dumpsys vibrator"` [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) output with a [BufferedReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html). 
It's updated once the vibrator finishes vibrating.