# How I can know if the vibrator is working? or is active ( vibrating ) - Android

Tags: android, developer-tools

How I can know if the **vibrator** is working? or is **active** ( **vibrating** )

Comment: Do you wish to know if another app has activated it, or if your own app has successfully activated it?

Answer (score 1):

To check if vibration is supported, you can use something like this

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
boolean isVibrator = mVibrator.hasVibrator();
```

The [`hasVibrator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#hasVibrator%28%29) returns true if vibration is supported by the device.

To detect if vibration is active, it is not currently supported by Android. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343366/vibration-listener-in-android))