# Detect if phone vibrates on device physical/software Keys

Tags: android, setting, vibration

in Some cases in your app you just wanna the phone to vibrate if
a certain button in your app has been clicked , in my case there is a search mode that switching to and from this mode will make the phone vibrate and also this would happen if the "back" key is pressed , and if the user has enabled the vibrate for software keys in setting then there will be 2 quick vibrates and its not cool , I was wondering if there is any way to detect this cause I cant simply disable it cause in some phones it may be disabled or the key is software so there wont be any vibrate at all 
thanks

Comment: do you want to detect vibrations?

Comment: @JasonBourne yea that's what I want , and any vibrations not just the ones I create ..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no listener for event handling vibrations. see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343366/vibration-listener-in-android)

you cant help with it even accelerometer or shake listener. It would be too weak to detect. 
See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) if it helps.

Comment: unfortunately these didn't help , just played with the method cancel() on vibrator object and couldn't solve it , also tried detecting it by shake listener and again no results , and the method on the other question you mentioned just detect the vibrates that are created by my app and so I guess  there isn't any way to do this

Comment: Yes, there is not a way actually. if found, keep me posted

Answer (score -1):

Use bellow code for vibration :

```
Vibrator v1 = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v1.vibrate(500);
```

Add permission in android manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: question was how to detect vibration, not creating vibration